# Is my error handling feasible when dealing items not found in an array?

Tags: c#, exception-handling

```
 internal void ShiftSwapInstrument(SwapCurve shiftedCurve, string swapToShift)
 {
    if (SwapExists(shiftedCurve, swapToShift))
    {
       var rateToShift = shiftedCurve.Swaps.Single(r => r.Description() == swapToShift);
       rateToShift.Rate = rateToShift.Rate + 1 / 10000.0;
       return;
    }
    throw new PdhSwapRateNotFoundException(swapToShift);
 }

 private bool SwapExists(SwapCurve shiftedCurve, string swapToShift)
 {
    var swap = Array.Find(shiftedCurve.Swaps, r => r.Description() == swapToShift);
    return swap == null ? false : true;
 }
```

The above code is what I've written to handle processing when an item is not found in an array. The exception should 'never' be thrown - it's truly exceptional if it does happen - thus I can use `Single` without reservation within the `if`-block.

My question is whether my exception handling is correct/feasible when items are not found in my array and is it correct for me to `return;` when I do?

***Secondary question***

I noted the following about [`Array.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa.aspx) on MSDN

> Return Value
>
> Type: T The first element that matches the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type
>   T.

Am I correct in my understanding, that since `SwapCurve` & `Swaps` are reference types the default value will be `null`?

Comment: Your code looks too complicated, look to shorter version in my answer, doing exaclty the same.

Comment: @ArturMustafin - complicated, how so? an excessive call or two is perfectly acceptable to me if it increases readability and understandability. You are correct, in that your version is shorter, but that extra second it takes me to understand the intent of the method six months from now to me is worth the 'complicated' code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error handling looks correct to me as long as your application is `catch`ing `PdhSwapRateNotFoundException` at some point and logging appropriate warning/error to notify user about this.

A slight cosmetic modification to your code could be like:

```
{
    if (!SwapExists(shiftedCurve, swapToShift))
        throw new PdhSwapRateNotFoundException(swapToShift);

    var rateToShift = shiftedCurve.Swaps.Single(r => r.Description() == swapToShift);
    rateToShift.Rate = rateToShift.Rate + 1 / 10000.0;
    return; // you don't actually need this.
}
```

And you're correct default value of reference type is `null`.

**Edit:**
I assume `shiftedCurve.Swaps` will not be `null`, otherwise Find will throw an exception. And if you think it could be the case then you may want to update your code to check for `shiftedCurve.Swaps == null` and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Cosmetic change looks good

Comment: What about readability and performance? and i think that call to SwapExists leads to excessive searches twice: first time in `ShapExists` call, another when the single actual value is changed. You can easily combine these two calls in one call to `SingleOrDefault<T>()`

Comment: re the Edit - `Find` returns the default value which is null. `Swaps` will never be null at this point

Comment: @ArturMustafin - Your suggestions makes sense, but the original question was about error handling. You downvoted my answer :-(, np, mate!

Comment: Array.Find is much faster then SingleOrDefault, so when talking about performance you are wrong!

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

**Step1:**

You'd better to improve readability of you code since the IL will be exacly the same:

**Step2:**

Remove excessive method calls by using extenstion method `.SingleOrDefault<T>(..)`:

```
 internal void ShiftSwapInstrument(SwapCurve shiftedCurve, string swapToShift) 
 { 
    var rateToShift = shiftedCurve.Swaps.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Description() == swapToShift)
    if (rateToShift == null) 
    { 
        throw new PdhSwapRateNotFoundException(swapToShift); 
    }
    rateToShift.Rate = rateToShift.Rate + 1 / 10000.0; 
 }
```